# Определить является ли графический адаптер программным или аппаратным

Tags: c++, dxgi

Можно ли по флагу у `DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC1` определить каковым является адаптер, программным или аппаратным, такое я проводил с `DirectX 12` на API `DXGI` версии 1.4, но не знаю работает ли такое с `DXGI` 1.0 ~ 1.1, т.к. енумератор имеет следующее определение:

```
typedef enum DXGI_ADAPTER_FLAG
{
    DXGI_ADAPTER_FLAG_NONE  = 0,
    DXGI_ADAPTER_FLAG_REMOTE    = 1,
    DXGI_ADAPTER_FLAG_FORCE_DWORD   = 0xffffffff
} DXGI_ADAPTER_FLAG;
```

Comment: А какой смысл использовать DirectX12 и устаревшие апи 1.0 - 1.1?

Comment: Сейчас использую DX11 а он судя по документации работает только с 1.0 и 1.1.

Comment: Ну тогда имеет смысл не перечислять адаптеры а вызывать `D3D11CreateDevice` с флагом `D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Программный адаптер можно также определить по коду производителя `VendorId` в соответствующей `DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC` структуре.

> New info about enumerating adapters for Windows 8
>
> Starting with Windows 8, an adapter called the "Microsoft Basic Render Driver" is always present. This adapter **has a VendorId of 0x1414 and a DeviceID of 0x8c. This adapter also has the DXGI_ADAPTER_FLAG_SOFTWARE value set** in the Flags member of its DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC2 structure. This adapter is a render-only device that has no display outputs. DXGI never returns DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED for this adapter.

Direct3D 11, конечно же, работает с и со всеми новыми версиями DXGI и нет нужды ограничиваться DXGI 1.1.